# Tasks are only available on a workspace folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Can't find an simple, basic solution anywhere for this problem so I figured it was worth posting it here.

When I go to run my code as a task, I get the following message: "Tasks are only available on a workspace folder" - I can't find a solution anywhere and I'm a beginner at Visual Studio Code so I might need the answer / solution explaining in more simpler terms.

*VSC Version = 1.17.0*

Comment: Please display your code. You have to display some efforts.

Comment: Hi; it was a simple print("Hello World") to test it and then I receive the error message about Tasks being only available on a work space folder, it happens regardless of the programming language in use.

Comment: you need to open the folder containing the file you need to run as a project folder in vscode

Comment: @suraj Thank you for your help! Your answer appears to have worked for me, much appreciated! : )

Comment: great.. added an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visual Studio Code treats the folder containing your program file as a *workspace folder*.

Your tasks created will be contained in a file `tasks.json` within a hidden folder **`.vscode`** inside your project or workspace folder.

So instead of opening the file directly to create a task, you need to open the folder as a project.

Comment: What does `task` actually mean in `VSCode`?

Comment: @Jos [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) should get you started. Older docs [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-v1)

Answer (score -1):

The "[Workspace launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-launch-configurations)" section of VSCode mentions:

> With multi-root workspaces, VS Code searches across all folders for `launch.json` debug configuration files and displays them with the folder name as a suffix.
> Additionally VS Code will also display launch configurations defined in the workspace configuration file.

Example of settings:  [`vscode-tslint/vscode-tslint.code-workspace`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-tslint/blob/main/vscode-tslint.code-workspace)

---

As an alternative, you can have [User level tasks to share them across projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044001/6309) since VSCode 1.42 (Jan. 2020).

But regarding workspace tasks, since VSCode 1.57 (May 2021), said tasks will have to be "trusted" by anyone opening the same workspace, assuming you have versioned and pushed the `.vscode` folder.

> ### Safe code browsing
>
> It's great that there is so much source code available on public repositories and file shares. No matter the coding task or problem, there is probably already a good solution available somewhere.
>
> However, using open-source code and tools does have risks and you can leave yourself open to malicious code execution and exploits.
>
> Workspace Trust provides an extra layer of security when working with unfamiliar code by preventing automatic code execution when a workspace is open in Restricted Mode.
>
> [image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_57/workspace-trust-editor.png]