# How to share tasks between vscode workspace folders?

Tags: build, visual-studio-code, dependencies, task, chain

My VSCode project is multi-root workspace. That is I have multiple workspaces each in separate directories, each has a .vscode folder.

I'm trying to build a workspace with dependencies between each module via build tasks.

I've tried to set dependsOn parameter for a task, but it yields a following error:

`Couldn't resolve dependent task 'build FOO' in workspace folder 'BAR'`
*(here BAR build task depends on FOO)*

Is there a better/correct/any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I have added a feature request for this. Vote (thumbs up at first comment) if you're interested: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185084

Answer (score 13):

You can have a `tasks` section in your `.code-workspace` file. There you can create a task like "Build all" and define `dependsOn` tasks. However, there you also cannot reference build tasks from the workspace folders (to me this sounds like a reasonable feature and I believe they should implement it at some time).
My workaround is to copy the relevant build task from the sub-tasks files into the `.code-workspace` file and reference them in my "Build all" task.

Example `.code-workspace`:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "proj-A"
        },
        {
            "path": "proj-B"
        }
    ],
    "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "Build A",
                "command": "make",
                "args": ["-j4"],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/../proj-A",
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": "build",
            },
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "Build B",
                "command": "make",
                "args": ["-j4"],
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/../proj-B",
                },
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": "build",
            },
            {
                "type": "shell",
                "label": "Build all",
                "command": "echo",
                "args": ["Building everything"],
                "options": {},
                "problemMatcher": [
                    "$gcc"
                ],
                "group": {
                    "kind": "build",
                    "isDefault": true
                },
                "dependsOrder":"sequence",
                "dependsOn": ["Build A", "Build B"]
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Note the `cwd` option in the individual build tasks. `${workspaceFolder}` seems to be set to the first path in the `"folders"` section. You could also set `cwd` to absolute paths.

This is a bit hacky and the fact that one has to copy the build tasks is not beautiful, but it works for now and it can be easily adapted once it is possible to reference tasks of sub-tasks files.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. You can use `${workspaceFolder:proj-B}` to define the specific workspace folder to use instead of the 1st.

Comment: I don't quite like putting folder specific task logic into the `.code-workspace` file. What if I want to have two `.code-workspace` files sharing some folders?

Answer (score 2):

Check if the new [VSCode 1.42 **User level Tasks**](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/ef884679b076116a331fc27020fc3b85d6ae2355/release-notes/v1_42.md#tasks) can help share a task.

> `tasks.json` is now supported at a user settings level.
>
> You can run the the `Tasks: Open User Tasks` command to create a user level tasks.
> **These tasks will be available across all folders and workspaces**.
> Only shell and process task types are supported here.